# Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at index.js:1:1)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I my project which has HTML, CSS, and javaScript code,   in HTML

`<button class="container-button" id="btn" onclick="toggleContainer()"></button>`

my index.js file looks like

```
import './src/css/main.css';

function toggleContainer() {
    show/container or hide
  
}
```

in my index.html file i have attached the javascript file like

```
<script src="/index.js"></script>
```

in browser console the error is

```
[Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at index.js:1:1)]
```

and when i click on the button i get

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: toggleContainer is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick
```

THE ERROR PERSISTS EVEN AFTER OING "type": "module",

Comment: Your `<script>` tag needs `type=module`.

Comment: I don't think you can import CSS in a JS script that easy, without some sort of a bundler.

Comment: Yea good point: what do you expect the import of a CSS file to do?

Comment: After adding type=module in the script tag i'm getting this error
"Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/css"

Comment: Note that when you use modules then `toggleContainer` will be in module scope, not global scope.  So you won't be able to directly invoke it from the HTML like that.  Invert the approach.  Instead of using the HTML to target the JavaScript functionality, use the JavaScript to target the HTML markup and add functionality.  See [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Comment: @MoinNawaz: If a request for a JavaScript file is returning the wrong MIME type then that sounds like a problem on the server, not in client-side code.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are trying to access `toggleContainer()` globally. Since it is a module JS file, the exported variables don't automatically get declared globally.

You will need to attach `toggleContainer` to the global object (i.e. window):

```js
// index.js
function toggleContainer() {
    ...
}

window.toggleContainer = toggleContainer
```

Also, importing a .css file directly inside a JS module file is not possible without a bundler (e.g. webpack, rollup, parcel, etc) with a loader that can handle CSS files. You will need to use a link HTML tag to import the CSS file.

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./src/css/main.css">
```